# Find contours within a specific area

Tags: opencv

I have detected all the contours withing a 640*480 image using openCV contour detection method. Among all of these contours, I want to find the contours that reside in a specific area I'll define. Can you give me any suggestions to do it?

Do I have to find the centro-ids of all the contours and check that they are residing in the given area ?

Comment: Can the contour be partially within the area?

Comment: Yes,  contours can be partially within the area.

Comment: It is appreciated if you could add an image. Upload image in imageshack.us and give link here, if you can't upload image here.

Answer (score 0):

With C++ as reference, let us suppose that you've saved the contours in:

```
vector < vector < Point > >contours;
```

then you can enclose the individual contours in Rects as shown:

```
vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
vector<Point> center( contours.size() )//center of each Rect


      for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
      {
            boundRect[i] = boundingRect( contours[i] );
            center[i]=Point(boundRect[i].x+boundRect[i].width/2,boundRect[i].y+boundRect[i].height/2)
      }
```

You now have the approximate Center of Mass of each contour. You can now check whether your center lies in the required ROI or not.